# Does anyone know if it is possible to use Low Search to search within one page

Tags: ee2, low-search, low

Does anyone know if it is possible to use Low Search to search within one page, rather than pulling all information from a channel. I'm developing a take away directory and users need to be able to search for menu items on each individual businesses page rather than through an entire channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript for something like this. Here's a jQuery tutorial:
http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/live-text-search-function-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

If each business' "page" is a single entry, then no - Low Search (like all EE search modules - and in fact, all search modules everywhere, including Google) returns one result per entry - you cannot have multiple individual search results for a single channel entry/page.

(Think: how would you jump to individual results scattered throughout a single page?)

Perhaps a javascript-based on-page search is a better solution? (Or let users use their own built-in browser page search instead?)